# Mouseover-trigger on Slider Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm changing the Standard WPF Slider's template. And I want it where you move your mouse over the area the slider occupies and the thumb starts an animation to change its size, even if the cursor isn't directly on top of the thumb.

But I don't know how to bind to a parent like that.

I'll try to post what I got without making it look nasty. Here's what I got that's relevant (I think. If you need more, tell me)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}" x:Name="SliderHorizontal">
                 <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                  <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                      <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource LeftRepeatButtonTransparent}">
                      </RepeatButton>
                  </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                  <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                      <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource RightRepeatButtonTransparent}"/>
                  </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                  <Track.Thumb>
                      <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Focusable="False" Height="20" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Template="{StaticResource SliderThumbHorizontalDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,-5.5,0">

                      </Thumb>
                  </Track.Thumb>
              </Track>
          </Grid>
      </Border>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             triggers galore
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

And here is the template for the thumb itself. It's the ellipse `grip` I want to change the size of.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderThumbHorizontalDefault" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Ellipse x:Name="grip" Fill="White" Height="15" Width="15" Effect="{StaticResource z-depth1}">
            </Ellipse>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                more triggers
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

How would I go about doing this binding?
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: To bind to a parents property you'll want to create a relative binding like such: `<Label Name="Parent" Width="100"><Border Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Label},AncestoryLevel=1},Path=Width}"` Then the width of the child border would be bound to the width of the parent Label. You can do the same thing with style triggers: (Next comment)

Comment: Continued: `<Style><Style.Triggers><Datatrigger Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Label},AncestoryLevel=1},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">"Setters"</DataTrigger></Style.Triggers></Style>` Is this what you're needing?

Comment: @CalebB Submit an answer, as an answer instead of as a comment. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that was what he needed before posting it as an answer. I should have clarified that intent. Just adjusted my last comment to reflect that inquiry.

Comment: @CalebB I don't really follow as to how I should implement this. Where should I place this code? In the ellipse or somewhere else? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Within the RenderTransform block I would add a scaleTransform

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
     .....
     .....
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
         <Canvas x:Name="canvas" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
             <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                 <TransformGroup>
                     <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                     <TranslateTransform X="5.5" Y="11"/>
                 </TransformGroup>
             </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

Then within the control template's triggers I would add the scaling up of the canvas.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="EnlargeThumb">
                <Storyboard TargetName="canvas" 
                            TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX" >
                    <DoubleAnimation To="2" Duration="0:0:0" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EnlargeThumb" />
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
   </Trigger>
```

Note the style and what not that I got is from the template extracted via visual studio.